# Data structures for a Blackjack game

Tags: ruby, data-structures, blackjack

I'm trying to learn how to use Ruby and as my first application I'd like to build a console based Blackjack game.

I'm not too familiar with the Ruby constructs and the only way I'll learn and feel at home is build things and learn from my mistakes.

I'm thinking of creating a Card class, and has a Stack class has a collection of Cards.

However I don't know exactly what built in type I need to use to hold these Card objects.

Here is my card class:

```
class Card

  attr_accessor :number, :suit

  def initialize(number, suit)
    @number = number
    @suit = suit
  end

  def to_s
    "#{@number} of #{@suit}"
  end
end
```

Since I'm coming from C#, I thought of using something like List Cards {get;set;} - does something like this exists in Ruby or maybe there is a better more rubyesque way to do this.

Comment: You made a very good decision by switching to Ruby. You'll love your life. :)

Comment: @Radek S: I really enjoy using the language, I can't wait to hit the sweet spot where I feel confident doing everything in Ruby.

Comment: @Radek: I love Ruby too, but I wouldn't say it is better than C#, just different.  Ruby is great, but I prefer static type safety and I can't stand it when I am hunting a bug for 10 minutes only to find it was a stupid typo.  All languages have their own set of pros and cons.

Comment: "I can't stand it when I am hunting a bug for 10 minutes only to find it was a stupid typo." That is programming in general and not limited to Ruby or any one particular language.

Comment: @the Tin Man: Not so in a language like C# or Java where compiling tells you exactly where things blew up.

Comment: I decided to start learning Python rather than Ruby, because I didn’t want to become a pretentious bastard.

Answer (score 2):

Ruby is a dynamic language, so it usually doesn't rely on strict compile-time type checking, thus making constructions, such as templatized `List<Card>` fairly useless. Ruby generally has one universal data type of ordered collections - `Array`, which closely mimics `ArrayList` concept of Java/C#.

So, unless you want `Stack` to be something special, you can just use `Array` as is:

```
@stack = []
@stack << Card.new(6, :spades)
@stack << Card.new(10, :hearts)
```

or extend `Array` in some way:

```
class Stack < Array
  # some ultra-cool new methods
end

@stack = Stack.new
@stack << Card.new(...)
```

Comment: Which approach would you recommend? Also, what exactly is :spades and :hearts - please don't assume previous knowledge I'm new! Thank you!

Comment: The syntax `:spades` is a Symbol literal, similar to a String literal of `"spades"`. Symbols, however, are immutable in Ruby and are generally used as ad-hoc descriptive constants.

Comment: Note that subclassing from core language classes is usually not a good idea. For example, calling `some = @stack.select{ ... }` will return an Array, not a new `Stack` instance. Instead, it's better (more powerful and controllable) to wrap and delegate instances of the class(es) you need.

Comment: @Phrogz - You're right, it's a bit of philosophical question - should result of selection retain properties of original `Stack` type, or it should become just a generic `Array`. For example, if `Stack` instance bears some significance in a game (for example, if a game includes stack counter and thus creation of new `Stack` would increase it), then most likely one wouldn't want to spawn `Stack` instances without control.

Comment: @Sergio Tapia: I'd just stick to `Array` for now, if I were you, as you can always switch to using more customized class implementing stack without any harsh API changes, if you'll feel the need to do so in future.

Answer (score 2):

Ruby's builtin `Array` type has methods for acting like a stack:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]  # arrays can be initialized with []
a.push(4)      # a is now [1, 2, 3, 4]
a.pop          # returns 4, a is now [1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

Two Ruby Quiz episodes were dedicated to blackjack. The solutions to the second one might give you some ideas: http://www.rubyquiz.com/quiz151.html